# Is this grammar ambiguous, or is it the library's fault?

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar

I'm using the [rust-peg](https://github.com/kevinmehall/rust-peg) parsing expression grammar library, but the principles should be generally understandable. I'm using the library to create a parser for go based on [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec). I'm having trouble getting if statements to parse, and I've distilled the issue down to a simple example.

```
sep
    = ( " " / "\n" )*

expression
    = "x" sep block
    / "x"

if_stmt
    = "if" sep expression sep block

block
    = "{" ( sep stmt )* "}"

stmt
    = if_stmt
    / expression

pub file
    = ( sep stmt )*
```

This grammar should (in my mind) parse a very simple language that contains two types of statements: If statements and expression statements. An expression can be `x`, or `x` followed by a block. An if statement is `if` followed by an expression, followed by a block. Here is an example input that my grammar fails to parse:

```
x {}
if x {

}
```

This fails to parse because the curly braces after the `x` in the if statement line are interpreted as a block as a part of the `"x" sep block` rule, and not a block as a part of the `if_stmt` rule. Unfortunately, this parsing library does not backtrack and try re-parsing this part of the line as the if statement's block when this fails. I have realized that if I switch the order of the `expression` rule so that it tries to parse `"x"` first, then the if statement parses just fine. This does create a problem for the line `x {}`, since the `x` at the beginning of the line parses as just a normal "x", and it backs out of the expression rule before it tries to parse the `{}`.

Do these limitations make the library incapable of parsing a grammar like this? Should I find another one, or just write my own parser? (I don't really want to do that)

### Edit

I experimented with the go grammar, and I discovered that it is not legal to put a struct literal (the `"x" sep block` example) in an if statement condition. I was thus able to disambiguate the grammar as attdona suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disambiguate your grammar:

```
simple_expr
    = "x"

block_expr
    = "x" sep block

expression
    = simple_expr
    / block_expr

if_stmt
    = "if" sep simple_expr sep block
```

I don't know rust-peg, I hope this may help to resolve the parsing of your grammar.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not have the same semantics. `"if"` should not be followed by a `block_expr`, it should be followed by an expression, then a block. The block following the "if" is not a part of the expression, it's a part of the if.

Comment: "if" meaning should be clear for anyone, evidently not for me ;). I've updated the answer, Check if it fits for you something like that.